# Count the number of occurrences of a char in a string?

Tags: .net, vb.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Count specific character occurances in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5193893/count-specific-character-occurances-in-string)

I have a delimeter in string that i have to validate. How can I count occurrences of that char. For now i have a next function.

```
Private Shared Function CountChars(ByVal value As String) As Integer
    Dim count = 0
    For Each c As Char In value
        If c = "$"c Then
            count += 1
        End If
    Next
    Return count
End Function
```

Any alternative solution that looks better?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5193893/count-specific-character-occurances-in-string has your answer

Comment: Your code is fine :) Perhaps make it generic by specifying the char as a parameter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Or you could use LINQ..

```
Private Function CountChars(ByVal value As String) As Integer

    Return value.ToCharArray().Count(Function(c) c = "$"c)

End Function
```

As Meta-Knight has pointed out it can be shortened to:

```
value.Count(Function(c) c = "$"c)
```

Comment: Nice answer, but you can remove the `.ToCharArray()` which is not needed!

Comment: I would argue that the CountChars function isn't even needed, because the code is so short. You could just call the Count method directly.

Comment: I prefer...`Value.Split("$"c).Length-1`

Comment: I suspect that my approach would be better on memory/performance as yours will create a new string for each instance of "$", where as mine will just count the instances in the existing char array.

Answer (score 2):

Simplest and most versatile way I can think of:

```
Private Shared Function CountChars(ByVal value As String, Byval delim as String) As Integer

    Return Len(value) - Len(Replace(value, delim, ""))

End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check the number of occurances in one more way. See the below code, if you find it better you can use that.

```
    Dim Occurrences As Integer
    Dim Start As Integer
    Dim Found As Integer
    Do
        Start = Found + 1
        Found = InStr(Start, "ENTERTAINMENT", "E")
        If Found = 0 Then Exit Do
        Occurrences += 1
    Loop
```