# How To count spaces in a richtext by a click of a button and insert it to a textfield?

Tags: vb.net, count

I want to count the spaces for every space existence in the text-field.

This is my function:

```
  Private Sub btncntspace_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As  System.EventArgs) Handles btncntspace.Click

    txtcountspace.Text = txttyping.Text.Length(" ").ToString
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to count the occurrences of the space character inside a given string. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9938835/count-the-number-of-occurrences-of-a-char-in-a-string) you could use a LINQ.

```
value.Count(Function(c) c = " "c)
```

Hope I helped!

Answer (score 0):

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim cnt As Int32 = 0
        If RichTextBox1.TextLength > 0 Then
            For i = 0 To RichTextBox1.TextLength - 1
                If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(RichTextBox1.Text(i).ToString()) Then
                    cnt = cnt + 1
                    MsgBox(cnt.ToString())
                End If
            Next
        End If
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim spacescount as Integer = 0
For Each character as Char in RichTextBox1.Text
    If character = " " then
        spacescount +=1
    End If
Next
```