# How to count the number of spaces and characters in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

I want to count the number of spaces and characters inputted in a textbox field.
Example

```
 textbox1.text - " 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 a b c"
```

I want to count the number of spaces and the characters

Then the result must be..

Dim spaces as integer, char as integer

spaces = 10 , char = 10

Comment: possible duplicate of [Count specific character occurrences in string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5193893/count-specific-character-occurrences-in-string)

Comment: I love when you can find the solution by just pasting the title of your question in Google and click on the first link...

Answer (score 1):

```
 Dim spaceCount, lettercount As Integer
 spaceCount= 0
 lettercount = 0
 Dim s As String = " 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 a b c"
 For Each c As Char In s
    If c = " " Then
        spaceCount+= 1
    Else
        lettercount += 1
    End If
 Next
 MsgBox(charcount)
 MsgBox(lettercount)
```

`For Each` will iterate each character within the `string` then it will check whether `c` is a space or not. if it is a space then increment the `spaceCount` else increment the `lettrtCount`

Comment: You may wish to change `If c = " " Then` to `If c = " "c Then`.  I'm not certain that will compile with Option Strict On.

Answer (score 0):

You can do as you want in a sort way.

**Try it**

```
Dim count As Integer = 0
textbox1.text = " 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 a b c"
count = textbox1.text.Split(" ").Length -1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim longstring As String = "aab c d e" 
Dim TotalLength As Integer = longstring.Length
Dim TotalSpaces() As String = Split(longstring, " "
Dim TotalChars As Integer = TotalLength - (TotalSpaces.Length - 1)
```

Comment: Describe a little bit about what you are doing here and how is this gonna help with the problem