# Vba Function that counts how many times a text is contained inside a string?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a very specific question

There is a native vba function that counts how many time a text (such as a word or even a single character) repeats inside other text (string)?

It would get as parameters two string values, for example, and return a integer/long value.

I looked among worksheet functions and I couldn't find any. Should I make my own one?

Thanks very much!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Count specific character occurrences in string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5193893/count-specific-character-occurrences-in-string)

Comment: Subtract the length of substituting the text out from the length of the original and divide the result by the length of the text. `=(LEN("Text and More Text, Text of all Texts")-LEN(SUBSTITUTE("Text and More Text, Text of all Texts", "Text", "")))/LEN("Text")` = 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it doesn't exist in vba, you should make your own.  You can write a loop using InStr, counting the number of iterations.  It should be pretty performant as it essentially won't have to do any memory allocations, and VBA's string functions are fast.